# Change cell's formula parameter with an 'If' statement

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I have this formula in a range of cells:

```
=IF(D3="","",(UNIQUE(Index(ImportJSON(E3, "/email"),2,1))))
```

It brings back a text response (an email address). In this case the only part that is of relevance is the `2` at the end.

I would like to set it so that if the text/email returned contains a specific word (say `info` or `sales`) for the formula to increment the number `2`, to one number higher - `3`, and so forth until finds it a value that doesn't contain the string that was defined in the IF statement.

The `2` parameter is merely responsible retrieving the respective row from column 1.

Is this possible?